# Synctex Go to source from pdf and comment package

Tags: forward-inverse-search, comments

Synctex is very usefull for me. Jumping between source text and the compiled PDF is is absolutely great.

But when I use **comment package:**

**in TeXStudio** ---
I can't switch from pdf to source.

**in TeXnicCenter and in TeXWorks** ---
there is file comment.cut opening.

How I can go to source (*my source*, not comment.cut file), using comment package?

Is this a known problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\includecomment{partA}
\includecomment{partB}

\begin{partA}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
\end{partA}

\begin{partB}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
\end{partB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I deleted \begin{partA} \end{partA} and use \if command of TeX, because it is very difficult to work without Synctex...

Comment: Not an answer but have you considered `fixme`?

Comment: OK, I can use another package, but why with package `comment` `synctex` don`t work?

Comment: I don't know. That's part of why my comment is not an answer. I was just offering a potential alternative.

Comment: @cfr, thank you. I suppose, your alternative can be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of the comment package it says

`For inclusions, in LATEX the block is written out
to a ﬁle \CommentCutFile (default “comment.cut”), which is then included`

My guess is that because of this behavior, synctex thinks that you did something like an `\input{myfile.tex}` only with the comment.cut file.

Eg, LaTeX thinks that you put the text in a file called comment.cut which was then included in the main document.

For that reason, synctex will jump to the wrong file.

My guess is that you would have to change the package comment or use a different package as suggested, perhaps using `etoolbox` package where you can define \iftoggle and then include portions of text at will by just changing a boolean in the preamble.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Well you don't need `toolbox` if you use e.g. `fixme`. That's why I suggested it...

Comment: @cfr I don't want to put everything in sticky notes, but i want to selectively include actual content. The OP gave no hint that he wants to manage sticky notes, or did I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

In case it is useful and to elaborate on my comment a little: [fixme](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixme) has a great many options for formatting annotations, inline notes and similar items. It also has four 'levels' of each type of command and environment from a mere note through a fatal error which will block compilation in `final` mode. It also supports 'targeted' annotations and comment environments, themes and a multiauthor mode. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fixme/fixme.pdf) has details.

Here is a small sampler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  draft,%   change to final to hide fixme notes
  author=,% only one author of notes
  singleuser
  ]{fixme}
  \fxusetheme{color}%   pick a theme or specify layouts as desired (see manual)
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffixmes

\section{A section}

\fxnote{Kant?}\kant[1]

\begin{anfxnote}{A longer note}
    \kant[2]
\end{anfxnote}

\fxwarning{Health warning?}This line should be accompanied by a warming heath.

A falsehood is here.\fxerror{This is an error.}

This is nonsense\fxfatal{So this fixme must be removed before compiling the final version!}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Colourful fixmes]

With this theme, the different levels of fixme are printed in different colours. Alternatively, these can be indicated in a prefix. Commenting out the theme specification in the above code:

[image: Black and white fixmes]

I have no idea how similar this might be to the facilities offered by `comment` but I've never had a problem going from PDF to source while using it.

Comment: Have you used todonotes and how do you feel it compares to this? For actual commenting and "sticky notes", this package looks pretty decent.

Comment: @Trefex I did try it at one point and had problems. I don't remember the details, though, and the package may have changed significantly since then. (It is several years since I tried it.) I think I actually tried `todonotes` first and found `fixme` after not getting the former to work for me.