# TeXworks' "Go to Source" fails with `tcolorbox`

Tags: tcolorbox, texworks, forward-inverse-search

I mainly use TeXworks (windows) as tex editor and I like its "Go to Source" command which allows to `Ctrl+click` somewhere in `.tex`  (or .`pdf`) file and cursor jump to  corresponding place in result (or source) window.

Some time ago I found that when using `tcolorbox` in source, the jump from pdf was not correct. Some other file were opened. I supposed that the way `tcolorbox` works could drive synctex to take wrong decisions like happens in [Synctex Go to source from pdf and comment package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163951/synctex-go-to-source-from-pdf-and-comment-package) or [TeXworks: synctex works only partially](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34931/texworks-synctex-works-only-partially). But now I've found that only loading `tcolorbox` it's enough to misbehave `Ctrl+click`.

As an example, type following source in TeXworks (v0.6.1)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

After compiling it a new preview window with the pdf result is created, and the focus is translated to the preview window. If you place the mouse over it and press `Ctrl+click`, the focus is translated to the source window.

Another valid options are: Open "Window" menu and select "Go to Source" command or type "Ctrl+'" as it's shown in "Window" menu.

All three options will change focus to `source` window.

Now delete the `%` from source and load `tcolorbox`. After compiling again, preview window gets the focus. If you select "Go to Source" command or type "Ctrl+'" the focus will change to source file, but "Ctrl+click" will open `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` and select line 17.

Why `Ctrl+click` behaves different from `Ctrl+'` in this case? What's wrong: synctex, TeXworks, `tcolorbox` or `pgf`?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour with TeXWorks on Linux (installed it right for this ;-)

Comment: The problem is known see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300079/goto-source-opens-pgflibraryfadings-code-tex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346215/todonotes-interferes-with-ctrl-left-click-in-texmaker

Comment: It does not occur with `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` alone, however.

Comment: The problem occurs with the `vignette` library since there `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` is included and new shadings are defined. It seems to be a `pgf` or TeXworks problem as Ulrike Fischer already commented. With SumatraPDF, I do not get this problem on Windows.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: While you have been here (;-)) : Please take a look on this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355201/overlay-for-lowerpart-of-a-breakable-tcolorbox

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for pointing me to this question. I missed that one in the flood of incoming messages... I think I have an answer for it.